# Staying in a else

Tags: perl

I wrote this code in Perl :
But it does not work correctly . I think it stays at the final else and while does not work.
By the way the goal of this program is to :

1.Receive users name and check it.

2.If the user name was equal to "javad" , print hello.

3.Else test user for a key.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#1.Greeting

@keys      = qw(test 1234 root);
$WhileTest = "True";
$i         = 0;

print "What is your name?\n";
$name = <STDIN>;
chomp($name);
if ($name eq "javad") {
  print "Hello !\n";
}

#2.Start for key testing

#instruction :? recieve the guess and compare it with keys list
else {
  print "Welcome $name\n";
  print "What is the key?\n";
  $UserGuess = <STDIN>;
  chomp($UserGuess);
  while ($WhileTest eq "True") {
    if ($UserGuess eq $key[$i]) {
      print "Successed !\n";
      $WhileTest = "False";
    }
    elsif ($i < 2) {
      $i = $i + 1;
    }
    else {
      print "Try Again :\n";
      $UserGuess = <STDIN>;
      chomp($UserGuess);
      $i = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your Perl programs should have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` as their second and third lines, unless you have a very good reason not to have them. These lines will make Perl itself tell you about many simple problems with the program. After adding them you will need to declare all the variables used with `my`.

Comment: Re "unless you have a very good reason not to have them", and no good reason not to have them exist. (Of course, it sometimes make sense to disable a specific warning, or disable warnings/strict for a small block of code, but that's not the same as omitting `use strict;` or `use warnings;`.)

Answer (score 6):

Change:

```
if($UserGuess eq $key[$i]){
```

to:

```
if($UserGuess eq $keys[$i]){
```

You should [use warnings;](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).  Had you done so, you'd have gotten these warning messages:

```
Name "main::key" used only once: possible typo
Name "main::keys" used only once: possible typo
```

It is also a good practice to `use strict;`, but you need to do a little more work to get there.